# Css - Sidebar with fixed title

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

First of all here's the code - http://plnkr.co/edit/Iq9bjzCljALHORYIRvhe?p=preview

Now, as you can see there are two parts - the sidebar title, with the red background color, and the sidebar items, which are with the black background color.

Now, what I'm trying to get is to make the scroll available only at the black background part of the sidebar, meaning the red title is fixed.

How may I do this?

here's the html code -

```
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="SidebarController">
            <a href="#" id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">Navigation</a>
            <div class="sidebar" sidebar-directive="state">
                <div class="topmenu">Menu</div>

                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navigation-items"> <a href="#">Link4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and here's the css code -

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
}
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -160px;
    transition: 100ms left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#navigation-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    background: rgba(3, 159, 244, .95);
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
}
.show {
    left: 0;
}
.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.navigation-items a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #444;
    color: white;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
.navigation-items a:hover {
    background-color: #222;
}
.topmenu {
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: In your plunker there aren't a red title nowhere. Update with the correct code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I'm see. I update your plunker. See it working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SwyhsdfeJtaNX7WU0Kao?p=preview

The changes are so simple:

```
.sidebar {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.navigation: {
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS:

```
.sidebar {
            position :fixed;
            top : 0;
            left : -160px;
            transition : 100ms left;
            border: 1px solid #f00;
            height : 100%;
        }

.navigation {
            list-style : none;
            padding : 0;
            margin : 0;
            height:100%;
            overflow-y:scroll;

        }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/AUzowwf0AOC9U7QLUlOW?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the help, but i don't know if you noticed that when the sidebar is close the scroller can be seen

Comment: You welcome, just set the `.sidebar {left : -175px;}` and it's done, however my code can't fit well because i couldn't see the red box before the update you do need to set the `ul` height to `calc(100% - 70px);` but in my case i couldn't know its height